# Как обеспечить навигацию между jsp файлами лежащими в WEB-INF?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Есть стартовая станица (`index.jsp`) которая является меню и ссылки с нее ведут на `jsp` файлы которые лежат в `WEB-INF`. Но когда я использую конструкцию `<a href="addition.jsp">Добавить пользователя</a>` получаю ошибку 404. Раньше все файлы лежали у меня прямо в `webapp` и к ним можно было получить доступ просто достраивая `URL` но теперь я получил задание обеспечить безопасность поместив все `jsp` файлы в `WEB-INF`. И ссылки внутренней навигации больше не работают.

Помогите пожалуйста, как мне обеспечить переход на страницу которая лежит в `WEB-INF`?

Так я маплю мой `index.jsp` и `addition.jsp` на который я должен попадать по ссылке  `<a href="addition.jsp">` которая на странице `index.jsp`:

```
<!--Homepage.-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.HomePageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!--Add user in database.-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.AddUserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addition</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Это сервлет который отдает index.jsp :

```
public class HomePageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }
}
```

И мой `index.jsp`

```
<body>
    <h2>Меню</h2><br />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="addition.jsp">Добавить пользователя</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Как это можно сделать по возможности без костылей? Спасибо.

Comment: Ни WEB-INF, ни то что в нём находится не доступны для навигации в браузере в принципе. Если у Вас на странице есть ссылка href="addition.jsp", то обязательно должен быть либо addition.jsp в webapp, либо url addition.jsp должен быть отображён на какой-то сервлет. Но тем не менее WEB-INF доступен для сервлетов и jsp, Через тот же dispatcher.forward или include

Comment: Обычно защищаемые таким образом jsp являются шаблонами представлений. Они доступны только через контролеры-сервлеты. На странице ссылки показывают не на jsp, а на url сервлета. А сервлет, выполнив всё что должен выполнит, для генерации  страницы форвардит на jsp, скрытый в WEB-INF. Т.е. должен быть href="addition" вместо href="additin,jsp"

Comment: @Sergey спасибо за ваш комментарий. Скажите я правильно вас понял что для того чтобы воспользоваться `jsp` файлами в `WEB-INF` я должен создать сервлет который будет отдавать эти `jsp`. Соответсвенно у меня нет возможности использовать `<a href=... а` только придумать что-то с  `<form>` для вызова сервлета который отдаст `jsp` лежащие в `WEB-INF`. В противном случае о доступе к содержимому этой папки можно забыть?

Comment: href тоже можно использовать. В принципе никакой разницы между action в form и href в a. И там и там нужно поставить url сервлета. В сервлете можно распознать был ли переход по ссылке или отправка формы (doGet|doPost), принять соответствующие меры и подставить любой jsp в зависимости от условий

Comment: @Sergey тоесть я могу при помощи `req.getParameter("href")` получить ключ и использовать его как флаг для условного оператора внутри сервлета? Но разве у тэга `<a>` есть атрибут  `method`? Если `action` в `form` соответствует `href`, то что соответствует `method` я же должен как-то определить каким методом запрос будет обрабатываться?

Comment: Когда выполняется переход по ссылке, то в сервлете срабатывает doGet(). <a> method не нужен. У него всегда GET. Если у формы поставить method="POST", тогда срабатывает doPost(). Этим можно воспользоваться чтобы отличать одно от другого.

Comment: И кроме того обработка и результат зависят от входящих параметров. Есть они, нет их, чему равны, Всё это формирует условия, по которым и предпринимаются те или иные действия. Есть в запросе параметр кнопки submit, значить надо выполнить addition, показать jsp с результатом, Нет - показать jsp ввода данных. Всё просто.

Comment: @Sergey а в момент отправки запроса по  форме <a>, этот запрос придет на тот же сервлет который отдал эту стартовую страницу? Просто я попробовал в методе GET у `HomePageServlet` напиасть `if (href != null && href.equals("add"))` (в jsp поставил <a href="add)и похоже что запрос приходит не к нему. А к кому тогда?

Comment: Во первых нет никакого параметра href в сервлете. А на странице должны быть href, соответствующие <url-pattern>. Чтобы перейти на  addition.jsp (через сервлет AddUserServlet), нужно чтобы на странице было <a href="addition"/>

Comment: Если хотите выделить `add` в сервлете, то нужно использовать методы для анализа `url`. а не параметры. `href` никаким образом в параметры не попадёт. Вот как можно в `HomePageServlet` определить, что был переход по href="add"  
 `if ("/add".equals(request.getPathInfo())) {...`

Comment: @Sergey а как соотносятся <url-pattern> и href? Если href="addition" а <url-pattern>/addition</url-pattern> это оно?

Comment: Да. Это оно. 12345

Comment: @Sergey о да! до меня на конец доперло! и все заработало! Спасибо вам большое. Простите что так долго мучал. Вы очень очень помогли...